# SoundCloud API - List user's followings usernames

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, soundcloud

I want to iterate through all of the user's followings and list their usernames. At the moment all I can get is an object containing a bulk of following information which I can't seem to do anything with. What I would like to do is take these followings, get their usernames and push these usernames into an array. Any suggestions?

```
        SC.get('/me/followings',function(followings) {


            console.log(followings);

            // For loop iterating through all of the user's followings
            for(i = 0; i < followings.length; i++)
            {
                // Push all of these likes into the 'meGenrePref' array
                console.log(followings[i].username);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please add the "*following information*" whatever it is to your question. Most of us don't have a ready API key to SoundCloud.

Comment: please delete your `oauth_token` from your comment. It is not supposed to be shared publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var meGenrePref = [];

SC.get('/me/followings',function(followings) {
    for(i = 0; i < followings.collection.length; i++) {
        meGenrePref[i] = followings.collection[i].username;
    }
});
```

Produces:

```
["Tom Misch", "fabric", "SØNDER.", "NIGHT CULT FM", "Mafia Kiss", "PUNKS MUSIC (FREE DOWNLOADS)", "Beatslappaz", "UFO-PROJECT", "BICEP", "MARTEN HØRGER", "MattWills", "Negativ", "Ollie James", "Saucy Music", "Ben Read", "Barely Royal", "INKLINE", "Bunk Audio", "Isenb3rg", "BUNNIE", "Ones", "Bachelors Of Science", "Aurbs", "JoeK", "Gramatik", "Al Pack", "Anita Magenta", "Gold Panda", "Ride.", "LYD", "Delo", "DJOKO", "Hushh", "Fête", "NOVKA", "Plump Djs", "Jaded", "Nu Aspect", "Rico Tubbs", "Saucy Vibes", "Nayla", "SOUNDMOOSE", "The Busy Twist", "EskyBeat", "BLANDA", "Kimyan Law", "Chris Gresswell", "Night Bass", "Blu Mar Ten", "MassMatiks"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be

```
var users = [];

SC.get('/me/followings',function(followings) {
    for(i = 0; i < followings.collection.length; i++) {
        users[i] = followings.collection[i].username;
    }
});
```